# Searching a CSV file python

Tags: python, csv

I have written a program to calll exchange rates from a file but it prints an output fo reach row, there is a logic error but i cant't find it.

```
import csv
exRtFile = open ('exchangeRate.csv')
exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
newCurrency = raw_input("Please enter the currency you would like to convert to: ")
for row in exchReader:
        currency = row[0]
        if currency == newCurrency:
            newRt = row[1]
            print(newRt)
            break

print("Sorry, that is not a valid currency")
```

file:

```
Pound Sterling,1
Euro,1.22
US Dollar,1.67
Japanese Yen,169.948
```

Comment: What delimiter are you using? Default would be comma, but I don't see any commas in your file.

Comment: could you please elaborate more, like what is expected output and what actual you are getting.

Comment: CSV(Comma delimited) in excel

Comment: expecting 1.22 but getting 'Sorry, that is not a valid currency' then 1.22

Comment: Could you please provide the exact content of the csv file, including commas? When I try to reproduce the problem, it does not print every line, but no line at all, because the lines are not split correctly.

Comment: the commas are in the file like showed in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is that it prints the `"Sorry..."` line even when it finds the currency in the file. To prevent this, you can [add an `else` to the `for` loop](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

```
for row in exchReader:
    currency = row[0]
    if currency == newCurrency:
        newRt = row[1]
        print(newRt)
        break
else:
    print("Sorry, that is not a valid currency")
```

This way, the `else` block will only be executed when the loop is exited normally, i.e. without `break`.

Comment: You beat me by 12 seconds!  >;-]

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the delimiter or your csv file; to me it looks like tab-delimited, so:

```
exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile, delimiter='\t')
```

Then you have to understand that `break` is only breaking out of the loop, not out of the whole program.  For that you will need to use `sys.exit()`.  But a nicer solution is the `else` clause for `for` loops:

```
for row in exchReader:
    currency = row[0]
    if currency == newCurrency:
        newRt = row[1]
        print(newRt)
        break
else:
    print("Sorry, that is not a valid currency")
```

Comment: Oh, you changed the tabs to commas in your question.  Then use `delimiter=','` of course (but that might also be the default).